# c++ pointer to const class member problem

Tags: c++, pointers, pointer-to-member

I'm having this problem with C++ classes. I would like to get pointer to `myBar` object and store it in `quxBar`. The reason is I would like to be able to check the value using `quxBar->getX()` but I would also like to prevent from accidentally modyfing it from Qux so I tried using `Bar const*`.

```
class Bar
{
private:
    int x;
public:
    void setX(int X) { x = X; };
    int getX(){ return x };
}

class Foo
{
private:
    Bar *myBar;
public: 
    Bar const* getPointerToBar(){ return myBar; };            
}

class Qux
{
    void myMethod();
    Bar const* quxBar;
    Foo *mainFoo;    
}

void Qux::myMethod()
{
    quxBar = mainFoo->getPointerToBar();
    std::cout << quxBar->getX();
    quxBar->setX(100);  // HERE!!!
    std::cout << quxBar->getX(); // returns 100
}
```

Unfortunatelly it doesn't work since I'm still able to perform `quxBar->setX(100)` with no compilation error.

Probably my approach is totally wrong, but using current "skills" :) I have no idea how to fix it.

Thanks in advance for any help and suggestions.

Comment: Could you at least post code that actually compiles?  When I fix all the obvious compilation errors (incorrect semi-colons and so on), I get several of the following error: `passing ‘const Bar’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘int Bar::getX()’ discards qualifiers`.

Comment: I think its your compiler at fault.  What compiler are you using?

Comment: You don't get an error at all or just on that line? You need a semi-colon at the end of your class definitions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think this is your actual code, firstly due to the syntax errors it has, and secondly due to the fact that it actually is correct (mostly). More specifically, with this piece of code, `quxBar->setX(100);` would result in compilation error.

However, `quxBar->getX()` would also be a compilation error, you need to tell the compiler that can be called on const objects, you do this by adding `const` at the end of the function signature:

```
int getX() const { return x; }
```

Perhaps in your *actual code* you had `Bar* const quxBar` instead of `Bar const* quxBar`; they mean two different things: The former is a **const pointer** to Bar, while the later is a pointer to **const Bar**. Eg. in the earlier case, only the pointer itself can't be modified, but the object it points to can.

Comment: Thanks, actually there wasn't any problems with "`Bar* const quxBar` instead of `Bar const* quxBar`". There was some problem with QList pointer I used in original code.